# MDC-react Tab content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, mdc-components

I am using the MDC react- tab

```
<TabBar activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
                handleActiveIndexUpdate={this.handleActiveIndexUpdate}>
                <Tab>
                  <span className='mdc-tab__text-label'>Javascript</span>
                </Tab>
                <Tab>
                  <span className='mdc-tab__text-label'>IOS</span>
                </Tab>
                <Tab>
                  <span className='mdc-tab__text-label'>Android</span>
                </Tab>
                <Tab>
                  <span className='mdc-tab__text-label'>Angular</span>
                </Tab>
              </TabBar>
```

How do I load the content of each tab ?

Comment: we have same problem do you have solution to this?